# web.xml and relative paths

Tags: deployment, tomcat, web.xml, descriptor

in web.xml i set my welcome file to a jsp within web.xml

```
<welcome-file>WEB-INF/index.jsp</welcome-file>
```

inside index.jsp i then forward on to a servlet

```
<% response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL("myServlet/")); %>
```

however the application tries to find the servlet at the following path

```
applicationName/WEB-INF/myServlet
```

the problem is that web-inf should not be in the path. If i move index.jsp out of web-inf then the problem goes but is there another way i can get around this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<% response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL("/myServlet/")); %>`
```

since the jsp is served from the WEB-INF directory the servlet url is also resolved from that relative path. adding a / before will resolve the url from the context root

Answer (score 0):

As I understand it, WEB-INF is a special folder containing configuration and classes used by your JSPs, you shouldn't put code intended for direct serving inside it.

Anyhow, have you tried /myServlet?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried to do it with the absolute path ?

```
response.sendRedirect(response.encodeRedirectURL("/myServlet/"));
```